# Location changes immediately from certain location to my current location in Skobbler map

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am new in `Skobbler map`. In my `Skobbler map`, I am getting my current location in `onCurrentPositionUpdate` method.

```
SKCoordinateRegion region = new SKCoordinateRegion();
        region.setCenter(currentPosition.getCoordinate());
        region.setZoomLevel(13);
        mapView.changeMapVisibleRegion(region, true);
```

So, it shows my current location.

[image]

When i move some distance from my current location by dragging the map like this:

[image]

But, after few 4 or 5 seconds later, it returns back to my current location immediately. What can be done to stop that movement because i want to return to my current location after pressing the button only.  In my button, i use:

```
 @OnClick(R.id.fab_gps)
    public void goToMyGpsLocation(View view) {
        if (mapView != null && currentPosition != null) {
            mapView.getMapSettings().setCurrentPositionShown(true);
       } else{
            if(Helper.isGPSEnabled(this)){
                requestCurrentPositionProvider();
           }else{
                Helper.alertbox("GPS not enabled", "Please enable gps before you are directed to your current location", this);
            }
        }
    }
```

In my `requestCurrentPositionProvider` method:

```
public void requestCurrentPositionProvider(){


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Permissions.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        } else{
            if(mapView != null) {
                mapView.getMapSettings().setCurrentPositionShown(true);

            }
            if(Helper.isGPSEnabled(this)){
                showSnackBar(findViewById(android.R.id.content));

                currentPositionProvider = new SKCurrentPositionProvider(this);
                currentPositionProvider.setCurrentPositionListener(this);
                currentPositionProvider.requestLocationUpdates(MapUtils.hasGpsModule(this), MapUtils.hasNetworkModule(this), false);

            }

            else {
             Helper.alertbox("GPS not enabled", "Please enable gps before you are directed to your current location", this);
                }
```

Something like `Camera` movement changes so rapid. How do i stop that? What can done on `onClick` method, so that i return my current location after pressing button only?

Answer (score 0):

```
mapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16), 5000, null);
```

This helps to animate your camera for 5 seconds,you can change time based on your requirement.

else try this

```
mapView.animateToLocation(new SKCoordinate(37.7765, -122.4200), 5000);
```

Comment: Where do I use this ? At `onCreate` or somewhere .

Comment: mapView.changeMapVisibleRegion(region, true);Below this code add it

Comment: Cannot resolve the method `animateCamera` . What can i do now ?

Comment: Again, cannot resolve the method `animateToLocation` .

Answer (score 0):

I understood that your `onCurrentPositionUpdate()` method contains:

```
SKCoordinateRegion region = new SKCoordinateRegion();
region.setCenter(currentPosition.getCoordinate());
region.setZoomLevel(13);
mapView.changeMapVisibleRegion(region, true);
```

This of course centers the map view according to your current location on every "current position update" i.e. location updates.

You have requested GPS location updates. If I've understood correctly those will then trigger the `onCurrentPositionUpdate()` method. (It's not really visible from the code snippets, but isn't that how a Skobbler map app. works...)

Even if you don't actually move there may be some fluctuation in the GPS location and the method may get called every few seconds.

If you meanwhile have dragged the map it will be centered back to the "current position" on each GPS location update.

So if you want to keep the manually chosen map state, don't always center it to the true current location on every location update in `onCurrentPositionUpdate()`.